# Python Dictionary not being filled?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to generate a random graph by first adding 20 vertices to it and then randomly match each of these with another vertex. The adjacency list is a dictionary.
When I try to add these to the graph I just get a key error and I'm not sure why.
Is the dictionary not being filled correctly?

Below is the code.

'''

```
class Vertex:

    # Constructor for a new Vertex object. All vertex objects
    # start with a distance of positive infinity.
    def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = label
        self.distance = float('inf')
        self.pred_vertex = None
        
class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.adjacency_list = {}
        self.edge_weights = {}
        
    def add_vertex(self, new_vertex):
        self.adjacency_list[new_vertex] = []
        
        
    def add_directed_edge(self, from_vertex, to_vertex, weight = 1.0):
        self.edge_weights[(from_vertex, to_vertex)] = weight
        self.adjacency_list[from_vertex].append(to_vertex)
        
    def add_undirected_edge(self, vertex_a, vertex_b, weight = 1.0):
        self.add_directed_edge(vertex_a, vertex_b, weight)
        self.add_directed_edge(vertex_b, vertex_a, weight)

g = Graph()
l = []

#add vertices 0-19 to the graph
for i in range(20):
    l.append(i)
    s = str(i)
    g.add_vertex(Vertex(s))

#connect a random vertex (0-19) with another random vertex
edges = [[random.choice(l), random.randrange(0, 20)] for i in range(10)]

#add these random edges to the graph
for i in range(10):
    g.add_undirected_edge(str(edges[i][0]), str(edges[i][1]), random.randint(0,100))
```

'''

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide an error trace.

Answer (score 1):

The keys in your adjacency list are not numbers, but `Vertex` objects.  That is why you are getting a key error, you are trying to look up the vertex using an str(integer), but you need to pass a Vertex object.

The simplest solution is to remove the `Vertex` class and just use the strings of the integers for your vertex labels and adjacency keys.  That would reduce your code to this:

```py
class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.adjacency_list = {}
        self.edge_weights = {}

    def add_vertex(self, new_vertex):
        self.adjacency_list[new_vertex] = []


    def add_directed_edge(self, from_vertex, to_vertex, weight = 1.0):
        self.edge_weights[(from_vertex, to_vertex)] = weight
        self.adjacency_list[from_vertex].append(to_vertex)

    def add_undirected_edge(self, vertex_a, vertex_b, weight = 1.0):
        self.add_directed_edge(vertex_a, vertex_b, weight)
        self.add_directed_edge(vertex_b, vertex_a, weight)

g = Graph()
l = []

#add vertices 0-19 to the graph
for i in range(20):
    l.append(i)
    s = str(i)
    g.add_vertex(s)

#connect a random vertex (0-19) with another random vertex
edges = [[random.choice(l), random.randrange(0, 20)] for i in range(10)]

#add these random edges to the graph
for i in range(10):
    g.add_undirected_edge(str(edges[i][0]), str(edges[i][1]), random.randint(0,100))
```

Another option is to store the adjacency using the string labels, but also store a mapping between the labels and the Vertex objects so they can be retrieved.

```py
class Vertex:

    # Constructor for a new Vertex object. All vertex objects
    # start with a distance of positive infinity.
    def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = label
        self.distance = float('inf')
        self.pred_vertex = None
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Vertex {self.label!r}>'

class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.adjacency_list = {}
        self.vertex_map = {}
        self.edge_weights = {}

    def add_vertex(self, vertex_label):
        self.adjacency_list[vertex_label] = []
        self.vertex_map[vertex_label] = Vertex(vertex_label)

    def add_directed_edge(self, from_vertex, to_vertex, weight = 1.0):
        self.edge_weights[(from_vertex, to_vertex)] = weight
        self.adjacency_list[from_vertex].append(to_vertex)

    def add_undirected_edge(self, vertex_a, vertex_b, weight = 1.0):
        self.add_directed_edge(vertex_a, vertex_b, weight)
        self.add_directed_edge(vertex_b, vertex_a, weight)

g = Graph()
l = []

#add vertices 0-19 to the graph
for i in range(20):
    l.append(i)
    s = str(i)
    g.add_vertex(s)

#connect a random vertex (0-19) with another random vertex
edges = [[random.choice(l), random.randrange(0, 20)] for i in range(10)]

#add these random edges to the graph
for i in range(10):
    g.add_undirected_edge(str(edges[i][0]), str(edges[i][1]), random.randint(0,100))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!
I still get an error when I try your second solution:  

'Traceback (most recent call last):  

  File  line 176, in <module>  
    g.add_undirected_edge(vertex_a, vertex_b, random.randint(0,100))   

  File  line 36, in add_undirected_edge   
    self.add_directed_edge(vertex_a, vertex_b, weight)  

  File , line 33, in add_directed_edge  
    self.adjacency_list[from_vertex].append(to_vertex)  

KeyError: '5' '

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error.  Try restring your interpretter?